# Prove that a number is prime iff the factorial of its predecessor is the predecessor of one of its multiples.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image]

I have tried to prove this via algbra but I got stuck. I was wondtering if there is any other way to prove this, like with a theorm.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: This is [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). The page also has a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the forward direction:
The case $n=2$ is easy.
Assume $n$ is an odd prime.  We know $(n-1)!$ is a product of units mod $n$.  If you pair up the elements which are not their own inverses mod $n$ they cancel.  You are left with a product of elements which are their own inverses.  But the only such elements are $1$ and $n-1$ since there can be at most two square roots of $1$ over any field.

For the backward direction:
If $n$ is not prime then one of the numbers $1,\dots,n-1$ is a zero divisor mod $n$ so the product cannot be congruent to $-1$ mod $n$.